# Can I add DDR2 total of 4GB or 8GB, how much for each slot?

Tags: memory

I ran following  in Ubuntu and got this result:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 64-bit ECC
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 2048 MB
    Supported Speeds:
        70 ns
        60 ns
        50 ns
    Supported Memory Types:
        DIMM
        SDRAM
    Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V
    Associated Memory Slots: 2
        0x0009
        0x000A
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM0
    Bank Connections: 1
    Current Speed: 160 ns
    Type: Unknown
    Installed Size: Not Installed
    Enabled Size: Not Installed
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM1
    Bank Connections: 0 5
    Current Speed: 162 ns
    Type: ECC DIMM
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer0
    Serial Number: SerNum0
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: PartNum0

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 72 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer1
    Serial Number: SerNum1
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: PartNum1
```

Motherboard info:

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: MSI
    Product Name: MS-7309
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

I don't understand if the maximum capacity is 2GB for each slot, but then it also says max 8GB so what is the maximum amount of memory I can add?

Comment: One is for the motherboard, the other is for each DIMM slot I think. So, if you have 4 slots, then each be up to 2GB (giving you a total of 8GB).

Comment: Nowhere does it say 2GB for each slot. It actually says 1GB for each slot with each controller having two slots. What motherboard is this?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz added motherboard info to post

Comment: why does it say 8GB in "Maximum Capacity: 8 GB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for "MSI MS-7309" suggests that it's MSI K9N6PGM2-V.

Searching for that model on MSI website gives me this [product page](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6PGM2-V.html).

On the *Specifications* tab there is:

> Max Memory (GB): 8

Comment: bu as the controller says: Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 64-bit ECC
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 2048 MB

doesn't that means I can install only up to 2GB mem?

Comment: You could easily buy 4 GB MoBo 8 years ago, yours is at most 6 years old so I think it should handle 8 GB just as MSI states. That 2 GB probably applies to one memory module.